# Find outliers in dataframe based on multiple criteria and replace with NaN using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, outliers

I am trying to make a function to spot the columns with "100" in the header and replace the values in these columns with NaN depending on multiple criteria.
For instance let's say I have a df where I want to replace all numbers that are above 100 or below 0 with NaN values :

I start with this dataframe
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = {'first_100':  ['25', '1568200', '5'],
            'second_column': ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
             'third_100':['89', '9', '589'],
            'fourth_column':['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
            }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
for col in df.columns:
    if "100" in col:
        df.loc[(df[col] > 100) | (df[col] < 0), col] = np.NAN

print(df)
```

output :

```
>>
  first_100 second_column third_100 fourth_column
0       NaN   first_value        89   first_value
1       NaN  second_value         9  second_value
2         5   third_value       NaN   third_value
```